# How to access static property of child class in php?

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php
class A{
    static $var;

    function test(){
      var_dump(self::$var);
    }
}

class B extends A{
    static $var = 'something';
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
?>
```

why does this print out null and how do I fix this? It works if I do not set $var as static but i need it to be accesible without creating an instance.

Comment: This is where `static` vs `self` comes in to play. If you change it to `var_dump(static::$var)`, it will you the property in the child class instead. Example: https://3v4l.org/oviE9

Answer (score -1):

`$b->test();` prints null because it is null. When you do this:

```
class B extends A{
    static $var = 'something';
  }
```

you're not actually doing anything to the `$var` property in your `A` class.  The property is defined with the static keyword, and [per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), "A property declared as static cannot be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a static method can)."  Thus you cannot inherit it (or subsequently set it) from your `B` class.

If you want the `test()` method to output anything meaningful, you need to set it statically, such as:

```
 A::$var = "something";
```

Comment: *"you cannot inherit [static properties]"* – Wrong: https://3v4l.org/GotZ4. You got the issue rather backwards.